# Imlib2 file loading error

Tags: imlib2

I have installed Imlib2 on my computer, however doing the example program as below (having changed the line for loading files to include the error code) I keep getting the error code 4.

```
/* standard headers */
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* main program */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* an image handle */
   Imlib_Image image;
   Imlib_Load_Error err;  
  /* if we provided < 2 arguments after the command - exit */
  if (argc != 3) exit(1);
  /* load the image */
  image = imlib_load_image_with_error_return(argv[1],&err);
  if(err) printf("load error:%d",err);
  /* if the load was successful */
  if (image)
     {
        char *tmp;

        imlib_context_set_image(image);

        tmp = strrchr(argv[2], '.');
        if(tmp)
            imlib_image_set_format(tmp + 1);

        imlib_save_image(argv[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated it to the newest update 1.4.10 and it worked.